# currentColor in gradient stucked in Chrome

Tags: css

When I set dynamically element's class with different color value property, gradient currentColor value stays the same. Live example: http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/jbWRZZ

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height:  200px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: red;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 50%, currentColor, transparent);
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in IE either. Seems fine in Firefox. Wonder if it has anything to do with how currentColor is computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome.

As a workaround, you can set the gradient in the `yellow` and `green` classes:

```css
.yellow {
    color: yellow;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 50%, currentColor, transparent);
}

.green {
    color: green;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 50%, currentColor, transparent);
}
```

([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVEJOa))

This will then behave as expected, changing the color when the buttons are clicked.

---

Note that you ***can't*** just set the gradient on `div.yellow, div.green`:

```css
div.yellow,
div.green {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 50%, currentColor, transparent);
}
```

([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaKRZz))

Doing that will result in the div updating *once*, then only updating after you've selected the element.

This probably triggers a repaint on the element, causing it to update.

Comment: Very strangely, IE seems to exhibit almost the exact same behavior to Chrome. The only difference is that Chrome repaints when you resize the preview pane.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thx, as I assumed, the best ways is just set background-image in every class again with actual color instead of currentColor

Comment: Accepting this answer, because there is no way make it work right in all latest browsers by the time.